# What is module Vs location Vs package in SystemJS configuration?

Tags: systemjs

I'm little confused by various terminologies used in the SystemJS configuration. It talks about **module, location, package** etc...

Isn't *module* in JS is a single file, and *package* is a collection of modules or files? If so, how a module can be an alias to a package?

This is from the [documentation page](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md):

> The map option is similar to paths, but acts very early in the normalization process. It allows you to map a module alias to a location or package:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes module is a single file, in javascript it's just the file name (with assumed `.js` extension) in quotes after `from` keyword in

```
import ... from 'some-module';
```

In SystemJS config file, `paths` and `map` can be used to define what actual file or URL that `some-module` refers to.

`packages` in config file allow you to apply a set of configuration parameters (default extension, module format, custom loader etc) for all modules in or below particular location (the key in `packages` object).

One of the settings in `packages` is `main`, which is similar to `main` in `package.json` in node (except that it's default value is empty, not `index.js`): it determines which file is loaded when the package location itself appears in `from` in `import` statement.

So, I think "how a module can be an alias to a package?" question about this

> The map option is similar to paths, but acts very early in the
>   normalization process. It allows you to map a module alias to a
>   location or package:

can be explained on this example:

```
paths: {
    'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
map: {
    'some-module': 'npm:some-module'
},
packages: {
    'some-module': {
        main: './index.js'
    }
}
```

when these `map`, `packages` and `path` settings are applied by SystemJS to

```
import something from 'some-module';
```

they will cause SystemJS to load a module from `node_modules/some-module/index.js` under `baseURL`.

and

```
import something from 'some-module/subcomponent';
```

is mapped to `node_modules/some-module/subcomponent.js`.

Note: this is based on my experience with SystemJS 0.19. I haven't tried 0.20 yet.